# WEKA is literally stuck halfway through classification once a new package in installed from package manager

Tags: html, django

I'm using WEKA 3.8 version and I have installed few packages from the package manager. Now when I try any classification algorithm, it takes too long and literally gets stuck with no output at all. Once I uninstall all the new packages from the package manager, WEKA works just fine. I have tried installing different versions of WEKA but the problem persists for all the versions that have a package manager associated with it.

It would be of great help if anyone could suggest solutions to this problem because I really need to use some of the external packages.

Comment: It might be useful to list the packages you're trying to work with.

Comment: I'm working with PSOSearch, RBFN and a package to compute EER value